# C++ console application always running in overtype mode

Tags: c++, input, console-application, windows-console

Awhile back, I had written a console application that performed some basic operations to output the coordinates of some points in an equally divided circle. It worked just as expected.

I decided to make some revisions and speed up the output with
`std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);`

It compiled just fine, but there were some distinct differences, even after I reverted my changes...

0. If I tried to use backspace, my input would be cleared up until a `>` , which I explicitly output. (This is normal.)
1. However, if I entered any input, moved the cursor before some input, and begin typing, I would now replace this input as if I were in overtype mode. From this point, I could now use backspace and delete **any** text visible in the console. This occurred regardless of whether it was my prior input, or the program's output.
2. Normally, `ctrl + <some character>` would input some character prefixed with a `^`. Something like `ctrl + e` would enter `^E`. Or, certain combinations like `ctrl + v` would paste. This was no longer the case. `ctrl + v` would no longer paste, but rather, it would enter some Replacement Character �. Other combinations like `ctrl + d` threw the program in a perpetual loop (which it normally is, but only after **some** input... this was effectively simulating a constant newline.)
3. The compiled program's file size had gone from 63kb to 159kb... (And this was after I removed the `sync_with_stdio` statement.)

I apologize if the question is a bit vague, I wasn't even sure where to start. All I can possibly say is it might be something with the compiler, as I had recently reinstalled my version of gcc, but I'm not certain.

[Link to my compiled version of the following Minimal Reproducible Example](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UvC5RzTI62xhCp90sbqK7I-Z3Nwi62Yk?usp=sharing)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int someInt;

    std::cout << "Enter an integer" << "\n";
    std::cout << "> ";
    std::cin >> someInt;
    std::cout << someInt;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make a [mcve] and it'll be easier for us to try it out too.

Comment: That all seems like it has more to do with the console you are using than with your program. Not all consoles are identical :-) In particular, pretty well all IDE consoles are idiosyncratic. And so is the Windows console.

Comment: Please paste the code into the question itself, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The problem is unlikely due to the code itself, as I encountered this issue after recompiling identical code. I've attached my compiled equivalent alongside the code for comparison.

Comment: I've tried compiling with msvc and it seems to execute as I would normally expect.

Comment: On further testing, it seems to be a problem with g++ 9.3.0 that was installed via msys using pacman. The g++ 8.1.0 that came with my version of mingw didn't have this issue...